# Pass data back to parent page without using modals

Tags: php, jquery

I' ve a request for a customer where there is a form in a page where  i can select from a list of (for example) jobs and others fields useless for this example.
If the job is not in the list, i need to click ADD ANOTHER ONE to OPEN A NEW PAGE where i can insert the new one.

parent.php:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">job 1</option>
  <option value="2">job 2</option>
  <option value="3">job 3</option>
</select>
<a id="btn-add-new" target="_blank" href="newjob.php">Add another one</a>

<submit>SEND FORM</submit>
```

My goal is, in the newjob.php, after the new insert, close the page (cause it's opened with _blank), and return new ID inserted and preselect the select in my parent.php with new ID returned.

newjob.php:

```
<input type="text" name="job_name" value="">
...
...
others fields ( a lot..)
...
...
<submit>Save job</submit>
```

**I know i can open a modal and using ajax to simplify it**.. but i need to use the already done `newjob.php` page cause it has a lot of others field and i don't want to duplicate it for a modal inside parent.php

Is there a solution for this or must i have done with modal and ajax and , of course, duplicate the HTML/PHP of the newjob.php to insert it into modal?!

Comment: Take a look at window.opener - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener - I have used this in past on Chrome

Comment: @DavidPartyka thanks for the solution, but it has a poor compatibility with browsers..

Answer (score 0):

You must do it on the same page. There is no other way. But you can use already working `newjob.php`.

Just do the ajax call to `newjob.php` and append it to modal.

**EDIT**

If you want to append only `<div id="primaryContentPage"...>` than in ajax do something like this.

```js
$.ajax({
    //your parameters...
    success: function (data) {
        $("yourModalId").append($(data).find("#primaryContentPage"));
    }
});
```

Where `yourModalId` is `id` of modal to which you would like to add the content of page `newjob.php`

Comment: in the newjob.php i've header, footer, lateral menu i don't need inside modal....

Comment: Yep, so you don't have to append the whole page. You can select whiuch element you want simply using jQuery.

Comment: ok i'll try to search for code. I've to include only div id="primaryContentPage" inside the modal.

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini Check out this [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments). You can load page fragments using the `.load()` method which sounds like what you're wanting to do...

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski hi, yes already tried. But modal page have a lot of script that doesn't work if I use partial code in modal. So i found another method. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found this usefull tutorial: https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-use-jquery-to-access-the-dom-structure-of-parent-html-webpage-from-within-the-child-html-window/

PARENT PAGE:

```
$(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('#linkToSpawnChildWebPage').click(

                function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    window.open('child.php','_blank','height=600,width=1024, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no'); 
                }
            );
        }
    );

<a id="linkToSpawnChildWebPage" class="actionLink">Spawn child web page</a>

<div id="messagesArea"></div>
```

child.php

```
var parentWindow = window.opener;

function addMessageToWebPage(msg) {

    $messageArea = parentWindow.$('#messagesArea');
    $messageArea.html("MESSAGE TO RETURN TO PARENT");

}

$(document).ready(
    function() {

        if (!parentWindow) {    
            //alert('Unable to get a reference to parent window.');       
        } 
        else {
            $('#messageForm').submit(               
                function(event) {
                    addMessageToWebPage($('#messageTextField').val());
                    //event.preventDefault();
                }

            );
        }       
    }
);
```

Comment: You may want to consider adding the relevant parts of the link to your answer. If the linked page ever moves or is removed, this answer will become invalid...